# how to localize robot with lidar in ros melodic

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, amcl, 2dlidar, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using `laser_scan_matcher` and `AMCL` nodes together to locate my robot in ROS Kinetic. Unfortunately, `laser_scan_matcher` is not working with ROS Melodic and `AMCL` is not enough. Are there any other packages to localize a robot by using lidars and odometry?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342200/how-to-localize-robot-with-lidar-in-ros-melodic/) by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2020-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-21**:
What do you mean that laser scan matcher doesn't work with ROS melodic? There's no reason that it shouldn't

**Comment by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on 2020-01-21**:
I mean it only has indigo and kinetic versions.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-21**:
Kinetic is essentially the same as Melodic. It will work fine.

**Comment by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on 2020-01-22**:
It is problematic to install laser-scan-matcher from source. I think somebody who use ros melodic, has to use laser odometry too. So, there must be a package to generate laser odometry. Are there any packages to localize a robot with lidar?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-01-22**:
Why is it problematic to build from source? That sound be straight forward.

Have you asked the maintainers to release it for Melodic?

**Comment by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on 2020-01-28**:
Well, I installed the `laser_scan_matcher` on `ros-melodic` and as you said it was straight forward. It was a bit scary to build a package from source but it works well. I am still confused if someone wants to use only `sudo apt-get install` command to install packages on `ros-melodic` how they can use navigation stack without laser odometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the guidance of the @stevemacenski and installed `laser_scan_matcher` with `catkin_make_isolated`. This package works very well in `ROS Melodic`. So to answer my own question, there aren't any packages like `laser_scan_matcher` in the `ROS Melodic`.

---

Originally posted by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) with karma: 57 on 2020-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karry3775](https://answers.ros.org/users/53272/karry3775/) on 2020-04-15**:
Hi could you provide some details on the installation. Thanks!
I am trying to install it on ROS Melodic as well.

**Comment by [wallybeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/46586/wallybeam/) on 2020-04-17**:
Please follow the instructions given bellow this [issue](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/scan_tools/issues/63#issuecomment-516967220). I followed the same steps.